# How to select SMA20 requirements in a google sheet dropdown box

Tags: android, google-sheets

How do I use the following SMA20 requirements, so that I can select each in a google sheet dropdown box, to filter data depending on what requirement is selected in the dropdown box. The requirements are in cells M4:M29, details of the requirements are:

No  SMA20
1   ALL
2   Price below SMA20
3   Price 10% below SMA20
4   Price 20% below SMA20
5   Price 30% below SMA20
6   Price 40% below SMA20
7   Price 50% below SMA20
8   Price above SMA20
9   Price 10% above SMA20
10  Price 20% above SMA20
11  Price 30% above SMA20
12  Price 40% above &SMA20
13  Price 50% above SMA20
14  Price crossed SMA20
15  Price crossed SMA20 above
16  Price crossed SMA20 below
17  SMA20 crossed SMA50
18  SMA20 crossed SMA50 above
19  SMA20 crossed SMA50 below
20  SMA20 crossed SMA200
21  SMA20 crossed SMA200 above
22  SMA20 crossed SMA200 below
23  SMA20 above SMA50
24  SMA20 below SMA50
25  SMA20 above SMA200
26  SMA20 below SMA200
The dropdown box is in cell B2, I do not know have to change the above requirements, so when they are selected in the dropdown nox, they are accepted by the query in cell A6. I have the following code in cell D2, which links to the dropdown box in cell A2.

=if(OR(B2="",B2="ALL"),"1=1","B "&B2&" and B is not null ")

This code also needs to be changed, because if you select any requirement other than any you get a Value error, because are not coded in the correct format. I tried using for example =if(A < B, A, ""), but this did not work because it is not in the correct format, and you cannot use = as the formula will become active, there by overriding the requirements. Other details are:
A.Code in cell A5 links to the code in cell D2,
B. Query in cell A6 links to cell A5.
I am using goigle sheets on an android. So any changed code for requirements or code in D2 would need to work on android. Please do not provide any Appt script code as this will not work on an android. So if anyone could help me with this problem it would be much aporeciated.

Link to sheet is below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccUYf0PQqiCamd1IktH7y3o1fMlgzYH7Jx0saomGqrU/edit?usp=drivesdk